# Apex HttpRequest with PATCH method to update Outlook 365 Event

Tags: apex, httprequest, patch

I am running into an issue which now bang my head. I just recognize that Apex doesn't support HttpRequest with PATCH method.
The Rest API to update event on Outlook 365 is

```
PATCH https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/{event_id}
```

I tried with many ways which I searched are:
append url with '?_HttpMethod=PATCH'  or

```
req.setHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override','PATCH');
req.setMethod('POST');
```

But none of them is successful.

```
System.HttpResponse[Status=Method Not Allowed, StatusCode=405]
```

Comment: Did you try with PUT as the method instead of POST using the override as well. if that does not work then you are out of options sans a proxy or possibly an ajax method on a VF page if the preflight passes cross-origin on the remote server

Comment: I tried with PUT also but not lucky. Outlook 365 allows PATCH only. Just think that Apex should support PATCH request.

Comment: @nlonguit Its a old post , but just curious , were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @RajuSen The only solution i could do is deleting the old record and then create a new one with updated fields.